# Using Putty/plink to connect to remote MySQL from Windows machine using Port Forwarding and multi hop SSH tunnel

Tags: windows, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, putty, plink

I need to set up port forwarding from my local Windows machine Port 3307 to a remote MySQL server port 3306 but accessed via 2 Linux proxy servers and a Linux web server.

I need to use Putty or plink.exe on the Windows machine to set up the connnection.

See diagram [image]

I've found examples using Putty GUI or plink CLI to achieve similar with only 1 proxy server but not with multiple hops.

I can achieve the connection I need on a *nix machine using
`ssh -N -L 127.0.0.1:3307:db-server:3306 -J user@proxy1 user@proxy2 user@web-server`

Trying to do the same using Putty or plink.

### Update

I ended up using OpenSSH on Windows.

The final command was a little different to above.

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:3307:db-server:3306 -J user@proxy1,user@proxy2 user@web-server -p 31001 -i "C:\path\to\private-key"
```

Note we were connecting to the final web server on port 31001, hence the `-p 31001`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no explicit requirement to use `putty`/`plink`, I would just use Windows built-in `ssh` for the purpose. It is the same SSH as in Unix.

Comment: I didn't realise! Going to try this.